# Assign static List to a non-static List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, static, instance

I came here because I have a strange issue with Unity and C# and I can't figure how to solve this.

I have two C# scripts :

- ScriptA is instantiated one time and has static variables. It has a static list which contains points for a path. This list changes over the time.
- ScriptB is instantiated several times (it is attached to enemies).
  On Start(), **it sets a non-static list equal to the current ScriptA.listOfPoint**

The issue is that it seems that this non-static list is updated with the   `ScriptA.listOfPoints`. I just want to have a list equal to `ScriptA.listOfPoints` state when this ScriptB was instantiated.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks in advance :)

**Static :**

```
//ScriptA    
public static List<int> listOfPoints = new List<int>();
public static void pathUpdate() //get called every 2secs
{
    //listOfPoints is modified
}
```

**Enemy :**

```
//ScriptB
private List<int> nonStaticListOfPoints = new List<int>();
void Start ()
{
    nonStaticListOfPoints = ScriptA.listOfPoints;
}
```

Comment: You need copy content of source list: `nonStaticListOfPoints.AddRandge(ScriptA.listOfPoints);`

Comment: You assign the reference. So `nonStaticListOfPoints` references the exact same structure as `listOfPoint` does. If you want to copy the values, you need to do something like `nonStaticListOfPoints.AddRange(listOfPoint)`.

Comment: Are you working with Unity game engine? There's unity3 tag intended for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you make that assignment you are not creating two lists but two variables holding references to the same list.

If you want a copy of list's elements, you can do [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
nonStaticListOfPoints = new List<int>(ScriptA.listOfPoints);
```

This creates a *new* list and copies the elements from the list passed into the constructor, so `nonStaticListOfPoints` can now be manipulated independently of `listOfPoints`.

Comment: Is this actually **cloning** though?

Comment: It's shallow cloning — the elements of the list are the same objects as in the first list.

Comment: @golergka Not in a `List<int>` they aren't. Either way, it's not really cloning of the list per se, it is iteratively copying the references/values held in its elements.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, of course — I must've missed the <int> part. In fact, it is true for every C# value type, be it a primitive type or a `struct`. Thanks for the correction.